# StackApps URL expansion in profiles does not work outside of MSE/StackApps

Tags: bug, profile-page, hyperlinks, stackapps

Title expansion for StackApps links in user profiles works on MSE, and on StackApps itself, but nowhere else.

On [MSE](https://stackapps.com/questions/7442/ro-chat-message-delete-option) / [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/users/25350/jason-c?tab=profile):

> [image]

On [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/616460/jason-c?tab=profile):

> [image: enter link description here]

Also, on [SE](https://stackexchange.com/users/305991/jason-c), it depends on where you copy the profile from. For example when copying it from SO:

> [image]

But if it's copied from MSE it copies the expanded titles as well. (Note: I originally edited my profile on MSE and saved to all communities; so I can confirm that expanded titles are *not* copied elsewhere and the source site doesn't matter, the copy behavior is just a unique SE thing.)

StackApps title expansion should work on all sites (all the other sites' titles expand properly everywhere).